# echo exec("sudo top -n1 | awk '/30100/ {print $9}'"); not printing anything

Tags: php, linux

The title is pretty self explanatory. I'm trying to get the CPU usage of a process by PID in PHP so I can display it in a webpage. The code works perfectly when written in the terminal, but doesn't print anything when done via PHP.

Tried

```
$cmd = "sudo top -n1 | awk '/30100/ {print $9}'";
echo exec($cmd);
```

where 30100 is the pid

and

```
$cmd = "sudo sh -c \"top -n1 | awk '/30100/ {print $9}'\" ";
echo exec($cmd);
```

[image]

I've also tried to $var = exec() and then var_dump($var) , the result was string(0)

I'd like to add that I'm using other commands on the system similar to this and they work fine. An example would be

```
$cmd = 'sudo -u server' . $sid . ' sh -c "pidof hlds_i686"';
$pid = exec($cmd);
```

which returns process pid

Comment: You know `exec` only returns the last line of output?

Comment: yes, but the output is only one line. It's the number representing %cpu usage, like 3.0. Edited OP with image

Comment: The only thought I have is to use the full path to `top` and `awk`.  The webuser may not have those paths in the environment.

Comment: Could you please provide the paths? I'm running centos6, and I don't know them. The answer doesn't pop up on the web either

Comment: Probably `/usr/bin/top` and `/bin/awk` but just do `which top` and `which awk` in terminal.

Comment: which'd both and the paths were as you provided. sudo /usr/bin/top -n1 | /bin/awk '/30100/ {print $9}' but still nothing in php. I'd like to add that I'm using multiple commands like this in php and they work fine, I'll add more info to the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an sderr / stdout issue , try using

```
$cmd = "sudo sh -c \"top -n1 | awk '/30100/ {print $9}'\" ";
echo shell_exec($cmd." 2>&1");
```

Comment: top: failed tty get. Searched around and found this http://pwong-tipsandtricks.blogspot.ro/2013/04/top-command-issue-on-cron-job.html . Added -b to top and now it prints 30100 server10 20 0 96352 60m 4412 R 4.0 23.7 106:14.70 hlds_i686 which is the correct information, but it doesn't only show the cpu like it should. Is there a solution for this? If not ill just parse it trough PHP

Comment: I'd use `pgrep 30100` if I were you, it seems much simpler